# The method 'delete' isn't defined for the class "AppJsImpl" flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have added firebase default options (await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform)) and firebase_core latest in pubspec.yaml,was worked previously, but not now.

```
../../software/flutter_linux_3.0.1-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database_web-0.2.0+15/lib/src/interop/app.dart:35:59: Error: The method
'delete'
                     isn't defined for the class 'AppJsImpl'.
[   +3 ms]  - 'AppJsImpl' is from 'package:firebase_database_web/src/interop/app_interop.dart'
            ('../../software/flutter_linux_3.0.1-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database_web-0.2.0+15/lib/src/interop/app_interop.dart').
[        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'delete'.
[        ]   Future delete() => core_interop.handleThenable(jsObject.delete());
```

Answer (score 3):

add `firebase_database_web: ^0.2.1` to pubspec.yaml solved the problem!